# Event handling in c++ using __event

Tags: c++, events

I'm trying to learn event handling in c++ using `__event`, `__hook`, and `__raise`. I can't find a simple code block anywhere to demonstrate the very basics of this.

Here's how I expect it to work:

```
class C // Class with event
{
public:
    __event void DoThing(); // Event method
};

void handler() // Event handler
{
    std::cout << "Handler" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    C c;
    __hook(&C::DoThing, c, handler); // Subscribe the handler to the event
    __raise c.DoThing(); // Raise the event
}
```

Though this code raises the following "error":

[image]

It still compiles and runs despite this but nothing is printed. What am I doing wrong? As a bonus question, how would I change the below to take a lambda event handler?

Comment: whenever you see something with double underscores it's either some internal, compiler-specific detail or someone <expletive deleted>ed up. You might not be able to find what you seek because you're not looking at the documentation for the right compiler.

Comment: @user4581301 so if I understand correctly, these "keywords" aren't meant to be used except internally?

Comment: They're a Microsoft [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/event-handling), and are deprecated for native C++ classes.

Comment: It looks like the [`__hook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/hook) call wants a member function as the last parameter, not a global one.

Comment: They may be intended for use by "outsiders", but they are not part of the C++ language and usually a `__` rather than a more ordinary name means that the identifier's not part of the regular API, so don't expect it to be supported or even exist at some point in the future. From 1201ProgramAlarm's comment it looks like it's been marked for death already. You should look into other alternatives. Not being much of a windows programmer, I'm not the guy to ask. If you tweak the question to something more like, "What should I use instead?" and tack on a `winapi` tag, there are folks who can help.